# extract Unique id from the URL using Python

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, url, automation

I've a URL like this:

```py
url = 'https://hp.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/ExternalCareerSite/job/Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1'
```

```py
x= 'Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1'
```

I want to extract id at the last of url you can say the x part from the above string to get the unique id.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

```py
_parsed_url.path.split("/")[-1].split('-')[-1]
```

I am using this but it is giving error.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from `url`?  What you show as `x`, or something else?

Comment: I want to extract the Unique id as x from url. I have got the solution for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) and [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) builtin libraries can help here.

```py
url = 'https://hp.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/ExternalCareerSite/job/Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1'

from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import PurePath

x = PurePath(urlparse(url).path).name

print(x)
# Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text *`Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1`* you can [`split()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/) with respect to the `/` character:

```
url = 'https://hp.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/ExternalCareerSite/job/Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1'
print(url.split("/")[-1])

# Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1
```

To print the text *`3103928`* you can replace the `_` character with `-` and you can [*`split()`*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) with respect to the `-` character:

```
url = 'https://hp.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/ExternalCareerSite/job/Enterprise-Business-Planning-Analyst_3103928-1'
print(url.replace("_", "-").split("-")[-2])

# 3103928
```